# Getting google/google play to work on an android 4.04 tablet

Tags: google-play-store, google-account, apk

Currently, the tablet seems to be in a chicken and egg situation:

Can't login to google (presumably) because of outdated software (we get a "invalid login" message, but the credentials are valid -- we tested on a computer), can't update the software because of lacking login to google.

So I ask: what should be installed to fix this? Perhaps a new version of google play, or that google services package? Would it be prudent to download those APKs from somewhere else instead of the google store?

I also presume that the most recent versions would not run. So what would be the latest versions that would accept to run on 4.04?

Comment: Plain Android 4.0 does not support TLS1.2 which is required for PlayStore access. Google has developed a workaround with a custom TLS library but I don't know how it is deployed. The only way I see is to install an updated version of Google Play Services and Google PlayStore. As updates have to have the same signature you can not install a manipulated or otherwise non-genuine app as update so matching APK files from third party websites are not a big risk (if the downloaded app is really an update).

Comment: According to [this news](https://9to5google.com/2018/12/07/android-ice-cream-sandwich-play-services-support/), Google Play services dropped support for Android 4.0.x ICS in December 2018 with v14.7.99 as the last version. There's [v14.8.49 on APK Mirror](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-services/google-play-services-14-8-49-release/) that still supports Android 4.0+, you might want to try it. However, the TLS 1.2 issue is more concerning since it has only been supported since Android 4.4.