# Sign-in and website issues on Motorola XOOM

Tags: google-play-store, connection-issues, stock-browser, motorola-xoom

My Motorola XOOM is having a few problems relating to internet and google accounts. Firstly, whenever I try to sign into any app using a gmail account, it gives

**"Your username and password don't match. Try again."**

alongside an account recovery info link. I've tried several existing accounts, as well as creating a new account. Secondly, any website I've tried to open from a Browser search gives

**"There are problems with the security certificate for this site."**

It's a very old device, so I wouldn't be surprised if there are issues with support being dropped, and I read that google play (Play Store on this thing) can cause issues on Android. I've tried a factory data reset and several restarts. It's on Android 4.0.4, and the device says it's up to date. I'm a bit experienced with electronics in general, but unfortunately networks/internet/connectivity is the one thing I'm lost in - please let me know if I missed anything.

Edit-
Play Store is currently on version 3.4.7.
Motorola XOOM MZ602, to be precise, on Android 4.0.4

Comment: Similar to: [Getting google/google play to work on an android 4.04 tablet](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/249793/3573)

Comment: I think your best bet is to flash a custom ROM with newer Android versions (preferably 4.4 KitKat or newer for TLS 1.2 support). Looks like [XDA Forums](https://forum.xda-developers.com/c/motorola-xoom.945/) has some custom ROMs for Motorola XOOM, but make sure it's mentioned for your device model specifically.

Comment: Huh, looks like my last reply went missing.. but thanks to both responses, I'll be looking into them. I'll have to do a bit of research on how flashing ROMs to tablets works, but I'm also considering, at that point, getting Ubuntu Touch on it as I originally intended lol. Although my understanding is that it runs on top of the OS, so it might not resolve the issue.

Comment: @Galaxy You're confusing Ubuntu Touch (no longer officially supported but being developed by a community at UBports.com) with chroot'ed Ubuntu installed on top of Android. The former is a full-fledged mobile OS that completely replaces Android. Now the bad news: Your device is too old and unsupported by any current Ubuntu Touch release. It had partial support, i.e., with 'hacks', some 10 years ago, apparently: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/ubuntu-touch-xoom-port.2171138/ (And no, you should NOT even try Ubuntu 12.10 even if you can find the old ROM).